# Why is the second property of a linear map called homogeneity?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, terminology

Why is the second property of a linear map called homogeneity?

**homogeneity**:
$T(av) = a(Tv)$ for all $a \in F$ and all $v \in V$.

in a definition about linear map properties in Axler.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, a function $f : V \to W$ between two vector spaces over a field $F$ is called [*homogeneous of degree $k$*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) if it satisfies

$$f(av) = a^k f(v)$$

for scalars $a \in F$ and vectors $v \in V$. The motivating examples occur when $V = F^n, W = F$ in which case we can take $f$ to be a [homogeneous polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial); in this case the degree $k$ in the above definition is the same as the usual degree of the polynomial. For example the polynomial $f(x, y) = x^2 + xy + y^2$ is homogeneous of degree $2$.

Google will tell you that one of the meanings of "homogeneous" is "consisting of parts all of the same kind," and a polynomial is homogeneous iff it can be written as a linear combination of monomials of the same total degree. I would be willing to bet that this is where the terminology comes from historically but I don't know for sure. I assume this is also where the terminology for [homogeneous elements of a graded ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring) comes from.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. One needs to be a little bit careful when identifying polynomials with polynomial functions, though (at least if $F$ is finite).